# Iterator of a Bean gives exception in Logs

Tags: java, struts2

I have a Bean like this

```
private String projectName;
private String projectCode;
```

It contains valid getter and setter.

Inside my Action class I am returning this as List and further passing on to JSP to be shown.

```xml
<select class="ibm-styled" name="selectedProjects" id="selectedProjects" 
        multiple="multiple"   tabindex="1"> 
    <s:iterator value="projectList">
        <option value="<s:property value='projectCode' />">
             <s:property value="projectName"/> 
        </option>
    </s:iterator>
</select>
```

From this piece of code in JSP, I am getting List of selected project codes in selectedProjects and they are getting set back in Action class after form submission.

Now, In action class, I need to iterate this selected project and get all Project Name in some String...I have written my code like this

```
if (selectedProjects != null) {
    String[] selectedProjectsId = selectedProjects.split(", ");
    StringBuffer ProjNames = new StringBuffer();
    Iterator<Project> iterator = projectList.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Project beanFromList = iterator.next();
        for (int ProjId = 0; ProjId < selectedProjectsId.length; ProjId++) {
            if (beanFromList.getProjectCode().equals(
                    selectedProjectsId[ProjId])) {
                ProjNames.append(beanFromList.getProjectName()).append(
                        ", ");
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(ProjNames);
}
```

Above code contains no error and all declaration are proper...I have scope of changing my code only in last mentioned snippets, Rest I can't touch.

I am getting following exception in Logs....

```
E ArchiveInputStreamData iterate unable to open file iterator
```

No Idea if its valid exception or not. I did debugging problem starts occurring the moment execution reaches to line declaring Iterator.

Kindly help me out here!!

Stack Trace

```
[7/1/14 20:48:33:731 IST] 00000020 annotations   E ArchiveInputStreamData iterate unable to open file iterator
                                 java.util.zip.ZipException: ZipFile closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpenOrZipException(ZipFile.java:424)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1100(ZipFile.java:40)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:456)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.fill(ZipFile.java:241)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:152)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:269)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:328)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:127)
    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:180)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(InflaterInputStream.java:232)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:152)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:157)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:103)
    at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.helpers.NestedArchiveIteratorDirect.getInputStream(NestedArchiveIteratorDirect.java:117)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.amm.scan.context.ArchiveInputStreamData.iterate(ArchiveInputStreamData.java:238)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.scan(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:257)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.scan(AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.amm.commonarchive.AnnotationsProcessorImpl.merge(AnnotationsProcessorImpl.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.processAnnotations(WARFileImpl.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.WARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(WARFileImpl.java:173)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl.getExtensions(WARFileImpl.java:440)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.WARFileImpl.getContextRoot(WARFileImpl.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.loadDeploymentDescriptor(Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.importMetaData(Ear50NoDDImportStrategyImpl.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.EARFileImpl.getDeploymentDescriptor(EARFileImpl.java:377)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.initializeModuleExtensions(EARFileImpl.java:641)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.EARFileImpl.initializeAfterOpen(EARFileImpl.java:720)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openSpecificArchive(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1517)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:1205)
    at com.ibm.etools.commonarchive.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.openEARFile(CommonarchiveFactoryImpl.java:552)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getArchive(AppInstallHelper.java:271)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.getEarFile(AppInstallHelper.java:157)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.utils.CommonUtils.getMergeEar(CommonUtils.java:450)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.admin.deploy.VerifyEJBandItsRoutersTask.performTask(VerifyEJBandItsRoutersTask.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:284)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:735)
```

Comment: We can't see your code--we don't know what `projectList` is, so it's impossible to help. I'd recommend using standard Java naming conventions (e.g., `ProjNames` is named wrong) and consistent indentation to make things easier to read.

Comment: If you have errors in the logs related to this question then you should post a full stacktrace. Without it is difficult to understand your error message, why and where it's occurred.

Comment: projectList is an Arrray List of Bean Type that I mentioned on top....The only Problem that is occurring is while using Iterator of Project type.

I am adding StackTrace of Exception as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys, This Problem is solved now. It was my mistake only. Project List that I was passing was empty So, iterator was throwing exception there.